# divided_by_five with partial and divmod

Tags: python-3.x

When try to write a `divided_by_five` with `divmod`

```
In [2]: from functools import partial    

In [3]: divided_by_five = partial(divmod, divisor=5)                               

In [4]: divided_by_five(10)              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-808446a06fa5> in <module>
----> 1 divided_by_five(10)

TypeError: divmod() takes no keyword arguments
```

I am little confused, `divmod` present in keywords list even though it's trivial. more confused it come without keywords arguments of dividend and divisor which might lead it to be barely less trivial (mirror to `pow(base, exp)`.

Is it possible to get a `divided_by_five` with `divmod` and 'partial'

Answer (score 1):

`divmod` does not accept any keyword arguments, let alone a `divisor` argument, hence the error you are getting. `partial` passes `divisor=5` to `divmod` but it has not idea what to do with it.

In general, `partial` can work with positional arguments, but only if you need to set the first one, and even then it is somehow error prone.

In this case you want to set the second one, so `partial` is not going to help as it will give the wrong result:

```
from functools import partial

divided_by_five = partial(divmod, 5)

print(divided_by_five(10))  # prints (0, 5) which is not what OP meant
```

It is calculating `5 // 10, 5 % 10` instead of `10 //5, 10 % 5`.

If you insist on using `partial` then a new "divmod" will need to be implemented:

```
from functools import partial

def divmod2(a, b):
    return a // b, a % b

divided_by_five = partial(divmod2, b=5)

print(divided_by_five(10))
```

Outputs

```
(2, 0)
```

At this point you might as well wrap the built-in `divmod` with a lambda:

```
divided_by_five = lambda a: divmod(a, 5)

print(divided_by_five(10))
# (2, 0)
```

Even though named lambdas are frowned upon it seems an overkill to use `def` for this.